# Tomcat 6.0.29 Start up issue

Tags: tomcat6

I have install tomcat on server 2003.

It was insatlled successfully, but when I was tyring to start it.

It's giving following error message in log files...

```
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:204)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1286)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:202)
```

Plz suggest the solution for this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

are you running from Eclipse?

If not you have some missing libraries, and most likely the downloaded Tomcat is corrupted - so download it again and have a go.

Comment: No i am not running it on eclipse.

Comment: No i am not running it on eclipse. I am running it on normal way means installed at c drive, it was installed properly, but when i was trying to start the service it is giving above error in log files.

Comment: @abhu74: I'd still suggest you try a fresh install if possible.

Comment: Ok I will fresh setup from tomcat site and then tell you the updates.

Comment: I had also done that but not get the solution. Will any tell me the solution for this... Thanks in advance