# Tomcat service stops automatically and gives the following errors in log files when try to start from services

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

**In Catalina File**
org.apache.commons.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:204)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1286)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:202)

---

**In Stderr File**
org.apache.commons.digester.Digester startElement
SEVERE: Begin event threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:204)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1286)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:202)

---

**In Stdout File**
Commons Daemon procrun stdout initializedCatalina.start: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2792)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2818)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1289)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1572)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:451)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.execute(Catalina.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.process(Catalina.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:202)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.ObjectCreateRule.begin(ObjectCreateRule.java:204)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:152)
    at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1286)
    ... 20 more

---

Please give me the solution for this, I had tried many thing but not get the solution.

Thanks in avdance

Comment: What version of Tomcat are you using?

Comment: is this the same problem from [2 months back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074529/tomcat-6-0-29-start-up-problem)?

Comment: The Tomcat version is  6.0.29 and 7.0.8

Comment: Ya its the same issue. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: @Abhu And yes, I realize you don't have enough reputation to upvote yet. All the more reason to adopt good posting habits now!

Comment: @Isaac Thanks for your suggestion. I will follow it in further posts.

Comment: @Isaac Will you please suggest a way to get a answer soon ...

Comment: @abhu74 This is a free site. Nobody gets paid to help you here. If you absolutely have to have an answer right now, you're better off hiring a consultant than trying to get free advise out of strangers on the internet. Based on my experience with Tomcat, I think Tomasz has pointed you in the right direction. I don't actually see where you addressed his question about your `PATH` system environment variable.

Comment: Friends Please give the solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely an installation problem, Tomcat wouldn't want to load a class that it doesn't have, at least not its own class ("org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" sits in catalina.jar since Tomcat 5.5). Seeing your previous question and this one I suppose you have a fresh and complete Tomcat installation, otherwise you're wasting the time. And you are on Windows ("starting the service", "installed on c drive"). So now check your search PATH - any other Tomcat or an older catalina.jar version out there coming before your current Tomcat's one?

Comment: I had also done that but after installing fresh tomcat, at time of installation the service was not started and when I was tried to start it from services(i.e. services.msc) its giving error 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly.

Comment: Again I had remove the tomcat and made the following things told by you.. 
1) Remove all registry entries like tomcat ,apache, catalina. 
2) Install fresh copy of tomcat. 
3)Set the environment variable for JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME. 
4)Empty the recycle bin and delete files from temp folder. 
5)Restart the system. 
Now try to start the tomcat from services but its giving the error. 

Could not start the Apache Tomcat 6 service on Local System. 
Error 1067:The process terminated unexpectedly. 


Please help me.